# urllib2 urlopen works very randomly

Tags: python, urllib2

For some reasons this part where I fetch JSON data from following url will only works sometimes. And sometimes it will return 404 error, and complain about missing header attribute. It will work 100% of the time if I paste it onto a web browser. So I'm sure the link is not broken or something.

I get the following error in Python:

`AttributeError: 'HTTPError' object has no attribute 'header'`

What's the reason for this and can it be fixed?
Btw I removed API key since it is private.

```
try:
    url = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/person?api_key=API-KEY&query=natalie+portman"
    header = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.16) Gecko/20110319 Firefox/3.6.16' }
    req = urllib2.Request(url, None, header)
    f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    print e.code
    print e.msg
    print e.header
    print e.fp.read()
```

Comment: @starcom I think you mean "sporadically" not "randomly". I doubt there is a RNG somewhere that determines if your code fails or not, even if it feels like it.

Comment: @Hooked yes that's a better word to describe it. Sorry English is not my first language ;(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As is documented [here](http://help.themoviedb.org/discussions/problems/135-little-api-v3-gotchas-that-should-get-documented), you need to explicitly accept JSON. Just add the second line after the first.

```
req = urllib2.Request(url, None, header)
req.add_header('Accept', 'application/json')
```